# Nonzero Octonions as a 7-sphere

Tags: abstract-algebra, octonions

While reading about Moufang loops in the book "An introduction to Quasigroups and their Representations" by Smith, I've encountered the following statement:

> The set $ S^7 $ of nonzero octonions of norm 1 forms a Moufang loop under multiplication. Geometrically, this set is a 7-sphere.

While I understand why this set indeed forms a Moufang loop, I'm not sure how it is viewed as a sphere, or what is the general connection between Moufang loops and this geometrical point of view. Could anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real  octonions are a [normed division algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_division_algebra), and in such a thing you always have a *unit sphere*. The unit sphere, because of multiplicativity of the norm, is always closed under the product.

The title of your question, though, refers to the *nonzero* octonions, and that is surly not a sphere (it has the homotopy type of a sphere, and in fact the unit sphere is a strong deformation retract---but I guess that if you know what this term means then you also are aware of this fact!)

Answer (score 5):

Mariano's answer is of course right on the money.

Since I myself happen to currently have my library's copy of Conway and Smith's book *Quaternions and Octonions*, let me recommend this book to you as well.  In general, throughout the book they continually emphasize a geometric approach to the algebraic structures mentioned in the title, so it would be a good place to read up on the topic of your question.